# Angular + Electron - Build and dist URLs

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I'm having a problem when I build the project with electron to call an UPDATE screen of the project in Angular since the dist has index.html, in development mode managed to call tranquility.

```
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:4200/#update');
```

in development mode I can call it that.

```
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
       pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html/#update'),
       protocol: 'file:',
       slashes: true
    }));
```

When I build the project I can not call the screen of the following error.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/dist/index.html#/update');
```

this way I managed to solve the problem

Comment: What was the difference between the two URLs in the end?

Comment: actually the **"/"** before the **dist**